# gsoap returns error 12 and "No user identifier provided" stream error

Tags: c++, gsoap

I am trying to build a simple gsoap client but am stuck.
This is the code, I wrote.

```
    CurrencyRatesSoapProxy currproxy;

    std::string login = "kav120@aubg.bg";
    std::string password = "mypass";


    std::string from = "USD";
    std::string to = "EUR";

    _ns1__GetLatestRate* getrate = new _ns1__GetLatestRate;
    getrate->SingleCurrencyFrom = &from;
    getrate->SingleCurrencyTo = &to;
    getrate->Password = &password;
    getrate->UserID = &login;


    _ns1__GetLatestRateResponse* resp = new _ns1__GetLatestRateResponse;

    if (currproxy.GetLatestRate(getrate, resp) == SOAP_OK)

        std::cout << "Works";

    else {
        currproxy.soap_stream_fault(std::cout); 
        std::cout << currproxy.error;
    }
```

Currencyratesoapproxy:

```
class SOAP_CMAC CurrencyRatesSoapProxy : public soap
{ public:
    /// Endpoint URL of service 'CurrencyRatesSoapProxy' (change as needed)
    const char *soap_endpoint;
    /// Constructor
    CurrencyRatesSoapProxy();
    /// Construct from another engine state
    CurrencyRatesSoapProxy(const struct soap&);
    /// Constructor with endpoint URL
    CurrencyRatesSoapProxy(const char *url);
    /// Constructor with engine input+output mode control
    CurrencyRatesSoapProxy(soap_mode iomode);
    /// Constructor with URL and input+output mode control
    CurrencyRatesSoapProxy(const char *url, soap_mode iomode);
    /// Constructor with engine input and output mode control
    CurrencyRatesSoapProxy(soap_mode imode, soap_mode omode);
    /// Destructor frees deserialized data
    virtual ~CurrencyRatesSoapProxy();
    /// Initializer used by constructors
    virtual void CurrencyRatesSoapProxy_init(soap_mode imode, soap_mode omode);
    /// Delete all deserialized data (with soap_destroy and soap_end)
    virtual void destroy();
    /// Delete all deserialized data and reset to default
    virtual void reset();
    /// Disables and removes SOAP Header from message
    virtual void soap_noheader();
    /// Get SOAP Header structure (NULL when absent)
    virtual const SOAP_ENV__Header *soap_header();
    /// Get SOAP Fault structure (NULL when absent)
    virtual const SOAP_ENV__Fault *soap_fault();
    /// Get SOAP Fault string (NULL when absent)
    virtual const char *soap_fault_string();
    /// Get SOAP Fault detail as string (NULL when absent)
    virtual const char *soap_fault_detail();
    /// Close connection (normally automatic, except for send_X ops)
    virtual int soap_close_socket();
    /// Force close connection (can kill a thread blocked on IO)
    virtual int soap_force_close_socket();
    /// Print fault
    virtual void soap_print_fault(FILE*);
#ifndef WITH_LEAN
    /// Print fault to stream
#ifndef WITH_COMPAT
    virtual void soap_stream_fault(std::ostream&);
#endif

    /// Put fault into buffer
    virtual char *soap_sprint_fault(char *buf, size_t len);
#endif

    /// Web service operation 'GetLatestRate' (returns error code or SOAP_OK)
    virtual int GetLatestRate(_ns1__GetLatestRate *ns1__GetLatestRate, _ns1__GetLatestRateResponse *ns1__GetLatestRateResponse) { return this->GetLatestRate(NULL, NULL, ns1__GetLatestRate, ns1__GetLatestRateResponse); }
    virtual int GetLatestRate(const char *endpoint, const char *soap_action, _ns1__GetLatestRate *ns1__GetLatestRate, _ns1__GetLatestRateResponse *ns1__GetLatestRateResponse);
}
```

and the *ns1*_GetLatestRateResponse:

```
    class SOAP_CMAC _ns1__GetLatestRate
{
public:
    std::string *UnregisteredUserEmail; /* optional element of type xsd:string */
    std::string *UserID;    /* optional element of type xsd:string */
    std::string *Password;  /* optional element of type xsd:string */
    std::string *SingleCurrencyFrom;    /* optional element of type xsd:string */
    std::string *SingleCurrencyTo;  /* optional element of type xsd:string */
    struct soap *soap;  /* transient */
public:
    virtual int soap_type() const { return 35; } /* = unique id SOAP_TYPE__ns1__GetLatestRate */
    virtual void soap_default(struct soap*);
    virtual void soap_serialize(struct soap*) const;
    virtual int soap_put(struct soap*, const char*, const char*) const;
    virtual int soap_out(struct soap*, const char*, int, const char*) const;
    virtual void *soap_get(struct soap*, const char*, const char*);
    virtual void *soap_in(struct soap*, const char*, const char*);
             _ns1__GetLatestRate() { _ns1__GetLatestRate::soap_default(NULL); }
    virtual ~_ns1__GetLatestRate() { }
};
```

I have no idea, what am I doing wrong but I get error 12 and "No user identifier provided" stream error.
smth like this:

```
SOAP 1.1 fault: SOAP-ENV:Client[no subcode]
"No user identifier provided"
Detail: [no detail]
```

I dont think ""No user identifier provided" is about the license info of service, because I obviously provided username and password. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't see a problem with your code. Code 12 only stands for SOAP fault, which you already knew, so there is no further information to gain from that. Is the service reliant, i.e. do you know that it returns correct response?

Comment: @nijansen It should, they have a sample app in their website that works, but their samples are not using soap service, though they claim that their services work with soap.

Comment: https://www.strikeiron.com/ this is their website

anyway, I think, I will search for another provider

Comment: @nijansen Sorry but I have another question. Which cpp files should I compile and link ? I have 1.XML files, 2.nsmap file 3. Proxy and Service cpp files 3. soapC.cpp 4. stdsoap2.cpp and .h files ?

Comment: You need to include the nsmap file once (this is important, it is not properly include guarded) and the header file of the proxy wherever it's needed. If you generated with option `-C` for client only, you can just compile every generated cpp file, plus the stdsoap2.cpp from the import directory. I also recommend generating with `-w` and `-x` option to omit the schema and XML message files which you do not need for your client anyway